# preforming operations on results from combinations.itertools in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to figure out all the 39 combination array of integers between 1-11. I can of course set up the basic iterations. It's of course a huge array and when I print it returns the location of the object. I don`t want to see all the iterations, I just want to preform a function on each of them. How do I select one of these iterations and run it through a function?

Comment: Can you show code and the error/erroneous output. Sounds like you may be printing out the `__repr__` of the combinations object. Cant be sure though.

Comment: Just use a loop, like `for combi in combinations(…): do_something(combi)`.

Comment: @PaulRooney It sounds like he figured out how to convert the combinations object into a list, or he wouldn't be complaining that it's hug and he doesn't want to see it? But I'm not sure, because of that "location of the object" bit, so…

Comment: `from itertools import combinations; for x, y in combinations(range(1, 12), 2):  # perform function` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the array to a variable, you need to simply iterate over it.

```
for item in iterator:
    # do something with item
```

In your case, your iterator will likely be a function from the `itertools` module.   Let me give a basic example so you can see how it might work.  In this example we loop over a million integers and only store the ones divisible by 6999.

```
output = []
for i in range(1000000):
  if i % 6999 == 0:
    output.append(i)
print(output)
```

You can apply this concept to your problem using an iterator from `itertools` module.